# pointers and structures being passed through functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

This might be a simple question but I've never come across something like it.  Let me start by saying I am working in standard C in a GCC compiler and this is for an embedded system.

I have a structure that holds an averaging array, running sum, zero offset, scale factor, divisor factor, and pointers to the averaging array.  Basically I declared this:

```
typedef struct  tag_avgAry {
    int array[AVG_ARRY_LEN];
    int *start;
    int *current;
    int *end;
    long sum;
    int avg;
    int factor;
    int zero;
    int value;
    unsigned char scale;
} avgAry;
```

So my issue is this.  I need to pass a structure created with this typedef and a data variable to a function that handles updating the running average and the array table with the new data.  I already have a function declared:

```
 void processArray(int data, avgAry array)
```

Now I know I need to change **array** to ***array** so that I'm actually modifying the structure I'm passing and not just a copy but how do I then handle the pointers that are part of the structure.  i.e.  if one of my stucts is called phA then to store the number 8 in the current element of the array in the structure I would write:

```
*phA.current++ = 8;
```

And would then check the "current" pointer against the "start" and "end" pointers and reset it if needed...  But if I do it through calling the processArray function as follows...

```
processArray(8,(avgAry *)(&phA));
```

how do I reference the pointers in the structure because my understanding is that to access, lets say, the sum element of phA in the function I would write:

```
*array.sum = data;
```

But would I write something like this if I wanted to access the pointer current?

```
*(*array.current)++ = data;
```

I'm sorry, its just been a long time since I've had to get this in depth with pointers and structures... Been spending too much time doing ASM I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `*(*array).current` but you could just use `*array->current`.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to access the array element would be the following

```
array[0]->current += data;
```

The `->` operator is short hand for `(*theValue).theMember` and is the preferred method for accessing pointer members.  The `[0]` indexer syntax is the preferred method for accessing array elements.  Using `*` directly on an array is acceptable though if you are doing pointer arithmetic

Comment: This... Very much this! I was reading OP question and became mad before finishing it, thanks Jared for bringing sanity and calmness back to my mind.

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand that, but in my situation my incoming member is simply called array for clarity. It is not actually an array but a structure that contains several variables, pointers, and one integer array as member of the structure.  So would I still do it the same way just leave off the [0]?

Comment: @user3221422 will have to know the exact type of `array` to answer that